# How to play bass part in Yann Tiersen's "Comptine d'ete no. 2"?

Tags: piano, sheet-music

How to play bass part (left hand) in Yann Tiersen's "Comptine d'ete no. 2" piano piece? Here the two sample bars (other bars has similar bass part):

[image]

I'm confused in strange notation, look at arrows. Does this mean that I should lift sustain pedal up on this notes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When notated like this, it generally means that you will hold down the note with one finger while the other fingers play the 8th notes.  Play the E with your little finger and hold it down, then use your index finger and thumb to play the B, high E, and B. Repeat for the F and so on.  I don't see any pedal markings, so no pedal should be used.

Comment: With the caveat that _touch_ of syncope pedal between the 4th and 5th quavers of the second bar is probably useful to help with the illusion that the low A is a semibreve (seeing how he will actually need to play it as two minims to articulate the second LH figure).